# ActiveRecord find with composite join

Tags: mysql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Suppose I want to do

```
SELECT persons.name, cars.registration FROM persons, cars 
   WHERE persons.state=cars.state AND persons.state_id_number=cars.owner_id_number ;
```

Hint: people in different states can have the same `state_id_number` but it is unique within a state.

I can do

```
People.find_by_sql("SELECT persons.name, cars.registration FROM persons, cars
   WHERE persons.state=cars.state AND persons.state_id_number=cars.owner_id_number")
```

to get a list of records.

But can I use the `find(:all, :conditions => {` format to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars,
      :foreign_key => "owner_id_number",
      :primary_key => "state_id_number",
      :conditions => "persons.state = cars.state"
end

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person,
      :foreign_key => "owner_id_number",
      :primary_key => "state_id_number",
      :conditions => "persons.state = cars.state"
end

Person.includes(:cars)
```

Comment: It needs to be `:conditions => proc { "cars.state = #{self.state}" }`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the association :cars setup

```
People.joins(:cars).where("persons.state=cars.state AND persons.state_id_number=cars.owner_id_number").all
```

Won't be exactly the same, but it should be close